# Espresso android automation tests - How to Access views of other application, opened by my application?

Tags: android, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation, android-espresso

I have a button in my app, that when clicked - opens dropbox login page on chrome.
I'm trying to access the views in that opened chrome window to fill the fields and continue, but because that activity doesn't belong to my application, the views are not in the hierarchy tree.

Anyone knows how to access external application views with espresso?

I already tried with "UI-automator" and "espresso-web", but to no avail.

Comment: [Espresso - Testing UI for multiple Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Android supports multiple windows. Normally, this is transparent (pun intended) to the users and the app developer, yet in certain cases multiple windows are visible (e.g. an auto-complete window gets drawn over the main application window in the search widget). To simplify your life, by default Espresso uses a heuristic to guess which Window you intend to interact with. This heuristic is almost always “good enough”; however, in rare cases, you’ll need to specify which window an interaction should target. You can do this by providing your own root window (aka Root) matcher: e.g. if you want to click on a pop-up which has "OK" and "Cancel" you can use Espresso like following.

```
onView(withText("OK")).inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())))).perform(click());
```

---

Another example is to use Espresso Intents: For example: User action that results in an external "phone" activity being launched as Clicked on the call button from your own app and you can verify using:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'
```

---

```
user.clickOnView(system.getView(R.id.callButton));
intended(toPackage("com.android.phone"));
```

Take a look at different examples mentioned on: 
[Official Google Android Test Forum](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/#intentstestrule)